# How to bind a image source in ControlTemplate from Code behind?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I need to bind the image source that defined in code behind into ControlTemplate. I have problem making it work correctly. I am wondering if someone can help.

The image is in ControlTemplate of the Button style. I instantiate that Button style in multiple XAML pages. My goal is to define 'Icon' instance in each code behind of these xaml pages to place the icon that is unique for each XAML page. Perphaps, it can be a better way to define unique icons that should be displayed in each XAML page where the button style will be loaded.

Below is the link to the solution I've created. It is a simple sample where I have 2 xaml pages with the buttons using the same style. I need to be able to load icon1.png into the button while mainWindow.xaml is opened and icon2.png when Page1.xaml is opened.

http://cid-0c29483cf3a6a14d.office.live.com/self.aspx/WPF%5E_Tests/BindingImageFromCode.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of solutions to your problem. You'll never know what the parent of your `Button` really is so a code behind Binding to a property for `Window`, `Page` etc. will be hard to accomplish without to much hardcoding.

### **Approach 1**

Subscribe to the `Loaded` event for the `Button`, find the `Image` in the `Button` Template with `FindName` and set the Source from there. This can also be done with an **Attached Behavior**

**Xaml**

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"
        Loaded="Button_Loaded"
        ...>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Image imgIcon2 = button.Template.FindName("imgIcon2", button) as Image;
    Uri uri = new Uri("Resources/icon1.png", UriKind.Relative);
    ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
    imgIcon2.Source = imgSource;
}
```

### **Approach 2**

Create a subclassed `Button` called e.g `ImageButton` where you add a new Property `UriSource` which you can bind to inside the Template.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
    <!--...-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                <!--...-->
                <Image x:Name="imgIcon2"
                       Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},
                                        Path=UriSource}"
                                        .../>
                <!--...-->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usable like

```
<local:ImageButton Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"
                   UriSource="Resources/icon1.png"
                   ...>
```

Also, I thought that you could bind to an Attached Property from inside of the ControlTemplate but that doesn't seem to be working..